# MySQL Which version one to use?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have asked how to DBSM and would like to proceed knowing more about MySQL.

When I log into their website, I dont know which one to try.

There are Community Server, Cluster, Workbench and Connector.

Please guide.

Note: I am working on excel database (which I found out on this website that it is not a good way to do it) with size of 1.34GB 63 files and growing. I would like to change and continue working in MySQL. I need the database for calculation, analysis and graph.

Comment: Thank you all for your support.

Is going for 64bit help?

Do I go with installation or stand alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, use the Community Server, and the Workbench. Community Server is the actual database, and Workbench is an application you can use to create the database schema (tables and views and users etc.) When you have got up to speed with writing sql queries, and importing your existing data, you can then use ODBC Connector to make the database available to excel as a data source for generating graphs.

Answer (score 1):

> MySQL Community Edition is a freely downloadable version of the world's most popular open source database that is supported by an active community of open source developers and enthusiasts.

Download Link: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Select your platform (windows, etc) and click the appropriate download button.

> I am working on excel database (which I found out on this website that it is not a good way to do it) with size of 1.34GB 63 files and growing. I would like to change and continue working in MySQL.

That's a rather large Excel file.  To get the data into MySQL once you've installed it:

1. Create a catalog (synonymous with "database")
2. Save the Excel data to CSV format
3. Use [MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to import content stored in CSV format into a table

> I need the database for calculation, analysis and graph.

MySQL can help with the calculation and analysis to some degree - you might have to create functions/stored procedures to get the functionality you desire.  Graphing however isn't initially what MySQL can do.  MySQL has spatial support, for overlaying on GoogleMaps but I don't know if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

[Community Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.4.html) is the database engine you're looking for.  You'll need the connector binaries (connectivity drivers) to easily access the MySql databases you create from other software.  The workbench is an administration interface that allows you to write ad hoc queries and manage database objects using a graphical user interface.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

When you say you're looking for graph support, it's not clear what you mean.

If you mean graph support like [creating charts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/CH001000373.aspx) in Microsoft Excel, I really can't help you. This has nothing to do directly with MySQL, and has everything to do with framework, libraries, and langauge that you're using to develop your website.

On the other hand, if you mean working with [graphs in the edges-and-vertices sense of the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) you might want to look into [OurDelta](http://ourdelta.org/about) which is a fork of MySQL that includes the [OQGRAPH storage engine](http://openquery.com/graph-engine-mysql-mariadb-and-drizzle) for performing graph manipulations easily in SQL.